# Measure pad size on Allegro Free Viewer 17.4

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, orcad, allegro

I need to measure the pad size(length and width ) of an IC pad.
May I know how to do the same in Allegro

I have highlighted one pad for your reference.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from the Cadence community. Please see the below link which clearly explains each step for measuring pad size.

https://community.cadence.com/cadence_technology_forums/pcb-design/f/pcb-editor-skill/51074/measure-pad-size-on-allegro-free-viewer-17-4/1380967?focus=true#1380967